# Mongoose how to add a method to model schema that executes every time a document is updated or created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema whose structure is somewhat like this -

```
var SaleSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    creation_datetime: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    account_from: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Account'},
    account_to: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Account'},
    transaction: {
        items: [{
            ref: {
                type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Item'
            },
            name: {
                type: String
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number
            },
            cost: {
                type: Number
            },
            discount: {
                type: Number
            },
            pricePerUnit: {
                type: Number
            }
        }],
        name: String
    },
    paid: {type:Number, default: 0},
    total: {type:Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Sale',  SaleSchema);
```

So, what I want to do is calculate total and cost of each item in the items array every time it is saved or edited.
I can do it in the controller function but I don't want to add additional complexity in that function, so Is there any way I can attach a pre method that can do it for me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below and update your document :

```
SaleSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
   // do stuff
   next();
});
```

Source:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre

Comment: How do I report errors according to some condition i set, like do I throw a return here, if yes then how to set the error status code.

Comment: You can do anything with next(). E.g If(someError){ return next(new Boom.notFound('Invalid'); } . I am using Boom for error handling you can use your error handler.

Comment: And also near the top of that section is this on [methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) that shows you how to add general methods, not tied to events :)